# SWI Thumb ASM command using registers

Tags: assembly, interrupt, thumb

I am trying to call a software interrupt on a THUMB processor using `swi` however I've got an issue in that I want to use a value that is stored in a register as the `x` part of this command `swi x`. Firstly, is this possible? Secondly, here's what I've tried:

```
 swi r0
```

I've tried other variations to no avail, however due to inexperience in Assembly I've not had much luck

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the encoding for swi it only has a version with an immediate not a register based one.

If you want to use a register, then set the register before the swi.  Then how you get at the register depends on what architecture you are on.  If a cortex-m then there is only one bank of registers.  If on a full sized arm then it is possible that it switches modes depending on what mode you were in when you called.  have to use a status register to figure out what mode you came from to figure out what bank of registers to pull from.  using the immediate is also tricky to figure out you have to disassemble to figure out arm vs thumb vs thumb2 versions of the instruction.  or enforce that the call comes from one mode.